# How to exit IPMI SOL session without exiting the ssh session?

Tags: linux, console, serial-port, ipmi, ipmitool

We can connect to IPMI serial over lan session by

ipmitool sol activate

and exit the session by

"~."

But "~." also exit the ssh session if you are in a ssh session.

"ipmitool sol deactivate" can disable the sol session without exiting the ssh session, but you need only another ssh session to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Quick answer:**

`~~.`

**Explanation:**

The ssh interprets the `~` character. So when you press just `~.` then ssh thinks it is a request to close the session. Ssh does not forward these characters and closes the session. ipmitool is closed because the whole session is closed. If you want send the character `~` to remote system you need to escape it. Ssh man page says:

> ... A single tilde character can be sent as ~~ ...

So `~~.` is forwarded as `~.` and it is then interpreted in ipmitool.

Another option is to override the default escape character in ssh. Ssh man page says:

> -e escape_char
> Sets the escape character for sessions with a pty (default: ‘~’) ...